# Collapse and expand Quick Launch in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, quick-launch

Is there an easy way (without writing code) to have headings on the `Quick Launch` so when you click the heading, it will reveal links?

And when you click the heading again, it will roll up those links?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve "collapse and expand for the quick launch" without using code.

Per my knowledge, you can achieve this using code. Below article is about using code to Expand/Collapse for the Quick Launch in SharePoint Online, which may be helpful to you. You can add the script in this article to a single page or to the master page if you’d like it to work on all pages in the Site Collection.

http://sympmarc.com/2015/05/27/simple-expandcollapse-for-the-quick-launch-in-sharepoint-2013-or-sharepoint-online/